# Need to check dictionary in another method, or make dictionary global

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, global

I need to see if a dropdown box has selected a key out of a dictionary. The dictionary is in another method (I believe its called a method). I've been searching how to make the dictionary global, but i can't figure out how to do it. Maybe there is a better way?

Thanks for any help, I wrote some code to show what I'm trying to accomplish below.

```
public void Dictionary()
        {
            var names = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
            names.Add("Kevin", new[] { 74.5, 6.35});
            names.Add("Rob", new[] { 2.5, 9.46}); 
        }

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in names)
            {
                if combobox.Text == kvp.Key
                {
                    solution = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Put the dictionary outside the method as member of the class(assuming both those methods belong to the same class).

Comment: you can declare ``Dictionary<string, double[]> names = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();`` outside function, and push data into a dictionary inside it.

Comment: Yes, your code is showing 2 [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods). Are both of these methods living in the same [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes#declaring-classes)?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, double[]> _names;

    public Foo()
    {
        _names = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
    }

    public void Dictionary() // note: this is just name taken from initial question
    {
        _names.Add("Kevin", new[] { 74.5, 6.35 });
        _names.Add("Rob", new[] { 2.5, 9.46 });
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _names)
        {
            if (combobox.Text == kvp.Key) // assuming you have already a declared "combobox" member
            {
                solution = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @JnJnBoo please check above question, I've actually used the exact same name as the post author, to make it readable for him. Please don't downvote because you miss the details. And there is no best practice to name dictionary as property. That's something used in backend programing when you need to create models matching the database, but not in general context.

Comment: @JnJnBoo please understand me correctly the intention here is not to call the method but demonstrate other aspects mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could handle this would be to return the Dictionary.

```
    public Dictionary GetDictionary()
    {
        var names = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
        names.Add("Kevin", new[] { 74.5, 6.35});
        names.Add("Rob", new[] { 2.5, 9.46}); 
        return names;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        foreach (var kvp in GetDictionary())
        {
           if (combobox.Text == kvp.Key) 
           {
             solution = true;
           }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the method public is what makes it accessible globally. There are a couple of missing pieces: the method itself is missing a return type, and it needs to be directly called from the combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged method.

It is best practice to not use a reserved name from the .NET framework in custom code - here I have changed the method name to GetDropdownChoices, added a return type, and then called the method outside of the foreach loop. For perfomance optimization, one suggestion is to use the .ContainsKey method instead looping through each item in a dictionary.

```
    public Dictionary<string, double[]> GetDropdownChoices()
    {
        var names = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
        names.Add("Kevin", new[] { 74.5, 6.35});
        names.Add("Rob", new[] { 2.5, 9.46}); 
        return names;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var choices = GetDropdownChoices();

        if (choices.ContainsKey(combobox.Text)) 
        {
             solution = true;
        }
    }
```